# Sorting each column in a nested list contained in an association

Tags: list-manipulation, associations, sorting

I have an Association which contains three arrays 200x1000x2.
Each row *m* of a matrix denotes a different set of parameters, while
each column *n* contains the outcomes of the function for a specific value of *x*.
Each elements is {*x*,f_m(*x*)}.

I want to sort each {*x*,f_m(*x*)} in a column in ascending order by f(*x*), so that the first row will now contains the lowest values of f(x), while the last row will contain the highest. Moreover, the elements should stay in their original column, so that all the elements in a column keep having the same value of *x*.
The rows will then be used to create a function that represents the envelope of the different outcomes of a Monte Carlo method.

I tried using `Sort`, together with `Transpose`, but the result is messed up.

Data Example with three 4x3x2 arrays:

```
<| 1-> 
{
 {{0.1,2.1},{0.2,0.7}, {0.5,-3.5}},
 {{0.1,4.2},{0.2,5.5}, {0.5,3.1} },
 {{0.1,5.6},{0.2,-6.4},{0.5,0.2} },
 {{0.1,7.4},{0.2,7.2}, {0.5,-8.2}}
},
2-> 
{
 {{0.1,4.5}, {0.2,3.5}, {0.5,5.6} },
 {{0.1,-3.1},{0.2,1.4}, {0.5,-7.4}},
 {{0.1,1.3}, {0.2,3.4}, {0.5,4.27}},
 {{0.1,-3.6},{0.2,-2.5},{0.5,0.2} }
},
3-> 
{
 {{0.1,3.6}, {0.2,7.2},{0.5,9.1} },
 {{0.1,-1.4},{0.2,1.3},{0.5,5.4} },
 {{0.1,2.3}, {0.2,3.4},{0.5,2.4} },
 {{0.1,-3.7},{0.2,5.6},{0.5,-6.2}}
}|>
```

and I want to obtain something like this

```
<| 1-> 
{
 {{0.1,2.1},{0.2,-6.4},{0.5,-8.2}},
 {{0.1,4.2},{0.2,0.7}, {0.5,-3.5}},
 {{0.1,5.6},{0.2,5.5}, {0.5,0.2} },
 {{0.1,7.4},{0.2,7.2}, {0.5,3.1} }
},
2-> 
{
 {{0.1,_3.6}, {0.2,-2.5},{0.5,-7.4}},
 {{0.1,-3.1},{0.2,1.4}, {0.5,0.2} },
 {{0.1,1.3}, {0.2,3.4}, {0.5,4.27}},
 {{0.1,4.5},{0.2,3.5}, {0.5,5.6} }
},
3-> 
{
 {{0.1,-3.7}, {0.2,1.3},{0.5,-6.2}},
 {{0.1,-1.4},{0.2,3.4}, {0.5,2.4} },
 {{0.1,2.3}, {0.2,5.6}, {0.5,5.4} },
 {{0.1,3.6}, {0.2,7.2}, {0.5,9.1} }
}|>
```

Comment: Example data please.

Comment: Instead of three 4x3 matrices, these are 3 arrays of dimensions {4,3,2}.

Comment: Do you mean `Map[#[[Ordering[#[[All, 2]]]]] &, asso, {2}]`?

Comment: Thanks for the answer Coolwater, however that function does not preserve the structure of the association. I'd like to keep the elements in their original column.  Edited the text for more clarity.

Comment: What do you mean by the "structure of the association?"  Your data seems structured <|1->{{{a1,b1},{a2,b2},{a3,b3}},{{c1,d1},{c2,d2},{c3,d3}},...}...|> It is not clear from this structure what you mean by "column," "row," etc. So if you could specify something like, "I want to sort by a, keeping the bs associated with the as. Similarly sort by c, keeping the ds associated with the cs." Or maybe it's the a1, c1, e1 series that you are wanting to sort on, keeping all of the 2s and 3s with the associated 1s? Basically, a clearer explanation of what it is you are trying to accomplish would help.

Comment: I've read the question five times. I still can't decode what it is you are asking. Please clarify, perhaps with a simplified before/after example.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestions, I edited for clarity and added the desired outcome.

Comment: I think you might have an error in your "after" example. If so, I believe `AssociationThread[
  Keys[#] -> 
   Transpose /@ (Map[SortBy[Last], #] & /@ Transpose /@ Values@#)] &` applied to your association does what you're after.

Comment: Yes, fixed it. Your solutions works very well, it is less visually compact than Henrik's but definitely faster.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
a = <| 1-> 
{
 {{0.1,2.1},{0.2,0.7}, {0.5,-3.5}},
 {{0.1,4.2},{0.2,5.5}, {0.5,3.1} },
 {{0.1,5.6},{0.2,-6.4},{0.5,0.2} },
 {{0.1,7.4},{0.2,7.2}, {0.5,-8.2}}
},
2-> 
{
 {{0.1,4.5}, {0.2,3.5}, {0.5,5.6} },
 {{0.1,-3.1},{0.2,1.4}, {0.5,-7.4}},
 {{0.1,1.3}, {0.2,3.4}, {0.5,4.27}},
 {{0.1,-3.6},{0.2,-2.5},{0.5,0.2} }
},
3-> 
{
 {{0.1,3.6}, {0.2,7.2},{0.5,9.1} },
 {{0.1,-1.4},{0.2,1.3},{0.5,5.4} },
 {{0.1,2.3}, {0.2,3.4},{0.5,2.4} },
 {{0.1,-3.7},{0.2,5.6},{0.5,-6.2}}
}|>

Map[Transpose[SortBy[Last] /@ Transpose[#]] &, a]
```

> <|
>
> 1 -> {
>
> {{0.1, 2.1}, {0.2, -6.4}, {0.5, -8.2}},
>
> {{0.1, 4.2}, {0.2, 0.7}, {0.5, -3.5}},
>
> {{0.1, 5.6}, {0.2, 5.5}, {0.5, 0.2}},
>
> {{0.1, 7.4}, {0.2, 7.2}, {0.5, 3.1}}
>
> },
>
> 2 -> {
>
> {{0.1, -3.6}, {0.2, -2.5}, {0.5, -7.4}},
>
> {{0.1, -3.1}, {0.2, 1.4}, {0.5, 0.2}},
>
> {{0.1, 1.3}, {0.2, 3.4}, {0.5, 4.27}},
>
> {{0.1, 4.5}, {0.2, 3.5}, {0.5, 5.6}}
>
> },
>
> 3 -> {
>
> {{0.1, -3.7}, {0.2, 1.3}, {0.5, -6.2}},
>
> {{0.1, -1.4}, {0.2, 3.4}, {0.5, 2.4}},
>
> {{0.1, 2.3}, {0.2, 5.6}, {0.5, 5.4}},
>
> {{0.1, 3.6}, {0.2, 7.2}, {0.5, 9.1}}
>
> }
>   |>

Comment: Thanks, this solution works! I had some problems explaining what I wanted to achieve, but you got it. Both yours and ciao's solution works well.